# Any one give me a solution for SORT

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, command

I want to sort data from shortest to longest line ,the data contains

```
  space ,character ,number,-,","
```

,i use `sort -n` ,but it did not solve the job.many thanks for help

Data here

```
0086
0086-
0086---
0086-------
0086-1358600966
0086-18868661318
00860
00860-13081022659
00860-131111111
00860-13176880028
00860-13179488252
00860-18951041771
00861
008629-83023520
0086000
0086010-61281306
```

and the rerult i want is

```
0086
0086-
00860
00861
0086000
0086---
0086-------
0086-1358600966
00860-131111111
008629-83023520
0086-18868661318
0086010-61281306
00860-13081022659
00860-13176880028
00860-13179488252
00860-18951041771
```

I do not care what characters ,just from short to long .2 lines with the same long can exchange ,it is not a problem .many thanks

Comment: You should provide sample data.

Comment: With an appropriately defined locale (one that treats all characters as equivalent for sorting purposes), you could simply use `LC_COLLATE=mylocale sort file.txt`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly define and install such a locale; maybe someone could pick this idea up and run with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl one-liner

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print join("\n", map {$_->[1]} sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map {[length, $_]} split /\n/), "\n"' file
```

Explanation on demand.

With GNU awk, it's very simple:

```
gawk '
    {len[$0] = length($0)} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (line in len) print line
    }
' file
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning

Comment: Both of these commands require you to store the entire file in memory.

Comment: +1 for the Schwartzian Transform. Just a minor nitpick ... the `END` block is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
(l = length($0)) && !($0 in nextof) {
    if (l in start) {
        nextof[$0] = start[l]
    } else {
        if (!max || l > max) max = l
        if (!min || l < min) min = l
        nextof[$0] = 0
    }
    start[l] = $0
    ++count[l]
}
END {
    for (i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (j = count[i]) {
            t = start[i]
            print t
            while (--j) {
                t = nextof[t]
                print t
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Output:

```
0086
00861
00860
0086-
0086000
0086---
0086-------
008629-83023520
00860-131111111
0086-1358600966
0086010-61281306
0086-18868661318
00860-18951041771
00860-13179488252
00860-13176880028
00860-13081022659
```

Another Version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
(l = length($0)) && !($0 in nextof) {
    if (l in start) {
        nextof[lastof[l]] = $0
    } else {
        if (!max || l > max) max = l
        if (!min || l < min) min = l
        start[l] = $0
    }
    lastof[l] = $0
    ++count[l]
}
END {
    for (i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (j = count[i]) {
            t = start[i]
            print t
            while (--j) {
                t = nextof[t]
                print t
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0086
0086-
00860
00861
0086---
0086000
0086-------
0086-1358600966
00860-131111111
008629-83023520
0086-18868661318
0086010-61281306
00860-13081022659
00860-13176880028
00860-13179488252
00860-18951041771
```

Comment: can you see my example data ?,plz help me